# How do I make sure a specific code snippet runs everytime a pytest testcase runs?

Tags: pytest, pytest-django

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestClass():

    def do_setup(self):
        # do setup

    def test_a(self):
        # do something

    def test_b(self):
        # do something
```

Before test_a and test_b test cases run I need do_setup() to be called. I am using pytest-django framework.

Kindly help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use method/function level setup teardown

```
def setup_method(self, method):
    """ setup any state tied to the execution of the given method in a
    class.  setup_method is invoked for every test method of a class.
    """

def teardown_method(self, method):
    """ teardown any state that was previously setup with a setup_method
    call.
    """
```

refer http://pytest.org/latest/xunit_setup.html#method-and-function-level-setup-teardown